# Using sqlfunctions in linqpad

Tags: sql, linq, linqpad

My LinqPad is treating SqlFunctions as an unrecognized class. The intellisense is underlining the class.

How can I call the library in my linqpad query?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Press <kbd>F4</kbd> and add the `System.Data.Objects.SqlClient` namespace.

Comment: I get this error: `NotSupportedException:This function can only be invoked from LINQ to Entities` How exactly is it useful then?

Comment: @Rakasi: `SqlFunctions` is for LINQ to SQL.  You want `EntityFunctions` in `System.Data.Objects`.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.entityfunctions.aspx